# What form were Adam and Eve created in?

Tags: sunni, hanafi, adam-and-eve

What does Islam say about Adam and Eve in terms of what state they were created in, i.e:

1. Were they created in physical form in paradise
2. Were they created in spiritual form in paradise
3. Were they created in physical form on earth
4. Were they created in spiritual form on earth

Comment: According to the interpretations, you will get different answers on this. But it is true that there are interpretations that state that they were created and lived in Earth.

Answer (score 1):

As I listen. 
They were created in paradise physically and spiritually. 
And lived at both on paradise and  on earth.
Allah o Rasool knows better.

Comment: This answer lacks evidences to support your claims (see [answer]).